# how to bind specific sql colums in datagrid in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i am working on important project where i want to show specific columns from  sql database into datagridview when i search by itemcode in textbox. i have written a code but it is showing error. can somebody help me?

my code is here

```
Public Class Form8

Private Const constr As String = "server= PANKAJ\SQLEXPRESS; database = pankaj billing software; integrated security=true"
Private bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource
Private dt As DataTable = New DataTable
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Private cb As SqlCommandBuilder



Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from stockdata", constr)
    cb = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    bs.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs


    dt.Clear()
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from customerdata where itemcode = @itemcode"

    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", TextBox2.Text)




    'Set AutoGenerateColumns False
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        'Set Columns Count
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3

        'Add Columns
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "stockId"
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Stock Id"
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "stockID"

        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "itemcode"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Item Code"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "itemcode"

        DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "item"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Item"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "item"
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt




End Sub
```

Comment: You need to include the error you are receiving.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'ColumnCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control.'

Comment: if i remove DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3 then it add only blank row

Comment: You should edit your question to include the error. It makes it easier for future people having issues. I am not a Forms dev so I cant be sure but it looks like you are clearing your datatable then setting a new command but you never execute the new command. Maybe you need to execute it and refil your dt? You are creating an adapter, executing a command, and immediately clearing the result too. You probably should eliminate the bits you dont need to make it easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The constructor of a DataAdapter takes a string and a connection as arguments. `New SqlDataAdapter(string, SqlConnection). You have passed in a string (constr) not a connection.
2. Only retrieve the data you need, not all the fields with "*".
3. Set up your DataGridView before you bind it.
4. Not sure what itemcode is doing in a customerdata table. Seems like a database design issue.
5. It seems you are setting the DataSource property twice.

I am not good at DataGridView (where is @Plutonix when I need him) so this could need some tweaking.

```
Private Const constr As String = "server= PANKAJ\SQLEXPRESS; database = pankaj billing software; integrated security=true"
    Private bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource
    Private dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Private cb As SqlCommandBuilder
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection(constr)
        'Get the real column names from your database for StockId, ItemCode and Item
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select StockId, ItemCode, Item From stockdata Where itemcode = @itemcode;", cn)
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", TextBox2.Text)
        cb = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        'Set AutoGenerateColumns False
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        'Set Columns Count
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3

        'Add Columns
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "stockId"
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Stock Id"
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "stockID"

        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "itemcode"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Item Code"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "itemcode"

        DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "item"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Item"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "item"
        'DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        bs.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
End Sub
```

Comment: your code is working fine. if i want to add some columns more which are not in sql database but on form.vb then what should i do? i have two textboxes and i want to add them both after these 3 columns from sql database.

Comment: @pankajbabbar I am sorry, I am not sure. I would suggest a new question on adding columns to a bound DataGridView. Show what you have tried and how it doesn't work.

Comment: Why the downvote? I like to know where my errors are.

Comment: No problem, I have made the same mistake.

Comment: Pls don't get angry. You have far more knowledge than me. I appreciate it. Keep helping people like me

Comment: I am not the least bit angry. I am not that far ahead of you. Keep up the good work.